# PHP mySQL query for updating row in table using variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

My PHP file contains the following function.  It works when I set the review column to `'$review'` and the `IdUser` to 2.  But I need to have the `IdUser` set to the variable `$user`.  What is the correct syntax to set `IdUser` to the variable instead of a constant?  (preferably in a way that avoids SQL injection attacks).

```
function addRatings2($review, $user) {  
    //try to insert a new row in the "ratings" table with the given UserID
    $result = query("UPDATE ratings SET review ='$review' WHERE IdUser = 2 order by dateTime desc limit 1");    
}
```

Comment: Is `$user` a string or an integer variable? Strings must be single-quoted just as you have `'$review'` and escaped via the proper method for whatever database API you are calling with `query()` (for example `mysql_real_escape_string()`).

Comment: $user is an integer value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the right syntax is to use

`{$var}` wherever you want the current value of var to appear, so in your case it would be

```
$result = query("UPDATE ratings SET review ='{$review}' WHERE IdUser = {$user}
order by dateTime desc limit 1");
```

Comment: oh and to avoid the SQL injection you must use                                                             the stripslashes and  mysql_real_escape_string functions

Comment: The {$var} isnt working.  However if I use single quotes '$var' it works for the review variable but not for the user variable (UserId='$user')

Comment: ooops nevermind I wasnt passing the userID as session in my PHP.  Your syntax os exactly correct!!!

Comment: It should but the other way would be to concatenate the var to the string like this   $result = query("UPDATE ratings SET review ='$review' WHERE IdUser = " . $user . " order by dateTime desc limit 1");    The dot (.) character is the concatenation operator in php

Answer (score 1):

//anti-injection

$user = (int)$user;

$review = mysql_real_escape_string($result);
//mysqli_real_escape_string will be better

$result = query("UPDATE ratings SET review ='$review' WHERE IdUser = $user order by dateTime desc limit 1");

Answer (score 1):

You must use single quotes for a string as you have done, but you don't need to for an integer

```
query("UPDATE ratings SET review ='$review' WHERE IdUser = $user order by dateTime desc limit 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

`function addRatings2($review, $user) {`

$review = mysql_real_escape_string($review);

$user = (int)$user

```
$result = query("UPDATE ratings SET review ='$review' WHERE IdUser = $user order by        dateTime desc limit 1");
```

}